# Table is Not Dropping in PostrgreSQL database

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I wanted to drop a table in my Postgres database on Heroku. But I haven't yet wrapped my head around South, so I decided to write a function:

```
def dropTable(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("DROP TABLE books_request CASCADE;")
    success = simplejson.dumps({"success":"success",})
    return HttpResponse(success, mimetype="application/json")
```

So now my `books_request table` has been dropped.

Then I went into the bash for my app on Heroku, and I did `python manage.py syncdb` hoping it would recreate the table anew, but it didn't seem to. Why?

Is there any way to force sync just that app?

I also got this error message which might be part of the problem while doing the sync:

```
Problem installing fixture '/app/bookstore/fixtures/initial_data.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
DatabaseError: Could not load sites.Site(pk=1): value too long for type character varying(50)
```

UPDATE:

I think the issue is the table isn't dropping in the first place because when I dump the data, I can still see the table. Why isn't it dropping the table properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using south you may need to run the migrate command. Additionally if it views the migration as already applied it won't re-run it. Try running the below and then adding the output:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I'm not using South because I don't know how to use it... Is it still possible to use it at this point now that I've dropped the table?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you probably didnt drop the table, you just think you have.

Make sure you are referencing connection correctly first by:

```
from django db import connection
```

Use django debug toolbar to see the sql that got executed and what happened. Or possibly use a debug program like pudb on the heroku shell to see whats going on.